# portrait and landscape orientation without using auto layout constraints

Tags: iphone, orientation, ios6

My iphone application supports both portrait and landscape orientation. To do this in new iphone 5 iOS 6 introduces a new property called auto layout constraint. But I need to support my application both iOS 5 and iOS 6. So I cannot use this constraints. Is there any way to do this portrait and landscape orientation without using auto layout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES you can do this very easily.

**For iOS6**

UIViewControllers, in which you need only PORTRAIT mode, write these functions

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

For UIViewControllers, which require LANDSCAPE too, change masking to All.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
    //OR return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Now, if you want to do some changes when Orientation changes, then use this function.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
```

**For iOS5**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mayuur. but how I can set the frames of the page elements ? Is it possible in xib?

Comment: for different orientations, you can stil set the Auto-resizing elements from the Xib. For manual changes, you would have to write in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for iOS5 and in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation for iOs6

Comment: Oh.. Ok.. in that case how can I give if iOS 5, call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and if iOS 6, call willRotateToInterfaceOrientation ?

Comment: that thing, iOS would handle it-selves! Although, if you need to check , you can get the current version by [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]

Comment: there is a also a new method called viewDidLayoutSubviews